# Why use BufferedImage over Graphics2D?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I've viewed several guides in Java game development and some of them modify a BufferedImage then display that to a Canvas. My question is, why not directly paint the image to the Canvas using Graphics2D? Why are we using a BufferedImage as a "3rd party" of a sort. Is there a benefit to this or could it be BufferedImages are used primarily for when you're working with an manipulating individual pixels?

Comment: I don't know how it exactly works underneath, but in some cases, you might see the code drawing the content on the fly on the screen. Ie: you can already see unfinished drawing cycles.

Comment: individual pixels from my experience, when you need to create effects and art on the fly that are not pre rendered images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a `Graphics2D` from any `BufferedImage` using

```
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)bufferedImage.getGraphics();
```

That way, you can use all the painting capabilities of Java2D and still have a `BufferedImage` with all its benefits (convolve operations, pixel manipulation, recomposition effects for transitions (e.g. fade) between game screens).

Swing's `JComponent` and its subclasses already provide **double buffering** capabilities, so you're right, you don't exactly need an extra BufferedImage for that. The differnce is that Swing repaints regions when they get dirty (for example when you move another window over your game viewport), this might interfer with your game updating the screen at regular (realtime) or controlled (for event-based games) intervals, so you might be better off using that extra buffer.